# Use Function as Supplier

Tags: java, function, generics

Because of inheritance, a leaf-class has to have a `Function<T, R>` which it uses as a `Supplier<R>`. (Ignore the passed parameter)

What is the best way to convey that the generic parameter type is not used and that null should get passed?

Comment: You could try `Function<Void, R>` - so only `null` can be passed.

Comment: Is Void a viable parameter? I thought it only implies "no return type" (Function -> Consumer)

Comment: `void` yes, but `Void` as a type can be used in such situations.

Comment: Sure, added the answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convey the notion that some variable, return type, parameter etc. can only be `null` the type `Void` can be used - there's only one valid value for this: `null`.

So in your case you could use `Function<Void, R>` to indicate `apply(null)` will always be called, so the function needs to be mapped to a supplier of sorts.
In general you'd want to use `Supplier<R>` instead but in cases where `Function` is required this could be an option.

The same would be true for consumers that would need to be represented as functions: use `Function<T, Void>` in those cases and return `null`.

Answer (score 3):

Use [java.lang.Void](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html)

> The Void class is an uninstantiable placeholder class to hold a reference to the Class object representing the Java keyword void.

It can't be instantiated, so only `null` can be passed as parameter.

```
class SomeClass implement Function<Void, YourResultClass> {
  //implement apply
}
```